# If a user directly enters two digits in the input box, the matDatepicker uses Today's date on the valueChanges event

Tags: angular, angular-material

matDatepicker is taking Today's date on valueChanges event if user manually insert two digits in input box

[image]

```
  <mat-form-field class="col-2">
    <input [matDatepicker]="fromPicker"  formControlName="fromPicker"
      id="search-date-from" matInput placeholder="Departure Date From" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="fromPicker" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #fromPicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="col-2">
    <input [matDatepicker]="toPicker" formControlName="toPicker"
      id="search-date-to" matInput placeholder="Departure Date To" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="toPicker" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #toPicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

ts file is

```
// Listen for and react to 'from' date selection
this.myForm.get('fromPicker').valueChanges
  .subscribe((fromDate: DateTime) => {
    const toDateField = this.myForm.get('toPicker');

    if (toDateField && fromDate && fromDate.isValid ) {
      if (!toDateField.value) {
        toDateField.setValue(fromDate);
      }
      this.myForm.get('toPicker').updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
    }

  });

// Listen for and react to 'to' date selection
this.myForm.get('toPicker').valueChanges
  .subscribe((toDate: DateTime) => {
        const fromDateField = this.myForm.get('fromPicker');

    if (fromDateField && toDate && toDate.isValid ) {
      if (!fromDateField.value) {
        const fromDate = toDate < this.today ? toDate : this.today;
        fromDateField.setValue(fromDate);
      }
      this.myForm.get('fromPicker').updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
    }
    
  });
```

I am trying to find a way to capture what the user entered in input box?
Or it should not use todays date if invalid date is entered.
Because I am populating ToDate field using valuechanges event

instead, I am trying to make it like below
For example if I enter 11 then it should take 11 date from current month

Comment: 2 digits is not a valid date, this is the normal behavior when you enter the wrong date format and leave the input (blur), what are you expecting for?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to capture what the user entered in input box? Or it should not use todays date if invalid date is entered. Because I am populating ToDate field using valuechanges event

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correctly implemented the date picker and all of its dependencies, you would need to provide a custom date adapter for it to work.

Here is an example to parse the date into dd/MM/yyyy format :

```js
{
  provide: DateAdapter,
  useClass: class CustomAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    override parse(value: any): Date | null {
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        const [day, month, year] = value.split('/');
        return new Date(+year, +month + 1, +day);
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: can we make it return Datetime value instead Date?

Comment: Don't know, didn't try, you can try it yourself !